# New to JavaScript and would like to know of a way of improving this line here:

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript through Khan academy and I have written this.

```
// function to create pixel locations on x & y axis incrementing every 50 pixels
var lineSpacing = 50;
var startingPosition = lineSpacing;

var Lines = function()
{

  for(var lineIncre = 0; lineIncre < 400; lineIncre++)// numer of lines drawn, if space between lines decrease, increase this value
  {
    var lineX = startingPosition /*starting line postion*/ + (lineIncre * lineSpacing); /*Space between lines after starting point(50)*/
    line(lineX, 0, lineX, height); 
    var lineY = startingPosition + (lineIncre * lineSpacing); 
    line(0, lineY, width, lineY);
  }

};

var pixel_Loc = function() 
{
    for(var pxLoc = 0; pxLoc < 400; pxLoc++)
    {
        var fSize = 12;
        var storeNumbers = startingPosition + (pxLoc * lineSpacing);
        var storeNumbersTwo = startingPosition + (pxLoc * lineSpacing); 

        if(lineSpacing <= 19) 
        {
            fSize -= 2; 
        }
        if (lineSpacing <= 15) 
        {
            fSize -= 4;
        }
        if (lineSpacing <= 10)
        {
            fSize -= 8;
        }

        fill(255, 0, 0); textSize(fSize);
        text(storeNumbers, storeNumbers, 9);
        text(storeNumbersTwo, 0, storeNumbersTwo);

    }
};

strokeWeight(2.5); 
stroke(255, 0, 0, 25);

Lines();
pixel_Loc();
```

I would like to know if anyone could help me with simplifying what I have written. - the main part that is making me think I could improve is this:

```
if(lineSpacing <= 19) 
{
    fSize -= 2; 
}
if (lineSpacing <= 15) 
{
    fSize -= 4;
}
if (lineSpacing <= 10)
{
    fSize -= 8;
}
```

Comment: Please checkout http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I think this is better for what you are lookign for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) doesn't have a migration option yet, I'll answer this here. If you ask questions like this on Stackoverflow, they may be closed. That's a much better place to ask!

To simply reduce the code footprint:

```
if (lineSpacing <= 19) fSize -= 2; 
if (lineSpacing <= 15) fSize -= 4;
if (lineSpacing <= 10) fSize -= 8;
```

Or you could store what to do in an object:

```
var sizeChanges = {
    19: 2,
    15, 4,
    10, 8
};

for (var space in sizeChanges) if (lineSpacing <= space) fSize -= sizeChanges[space];
```

Comment: OK then, thank you. I was just wondering if there was a way around using so many if statements for something like that. And thank you for your input, I will consider that the next time I have an issue.